# Elasticsearch term query not matching special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ES index with dynamic mappings, there is an field called `createdBy`, looking at the mappings created by ES I see this field is of `string` type, which is good (not analyzed, not `text`)

However the following query does not return any matches:

```
GET named-entities/_search?size=1
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
          "createdBy": "google-oauth2|1234567890"
    }
  }
}
```

but changing the `term` query to a `match` query works, i.e. this works:

```
GET named-entities/_search?size=1
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
          "createdBy": "google-oauth2|1234567890"
    }
  }
}
```

but that is not what I want, I would like this field to not be analyzed. could anyone enlighten me on what could be going wrong here?

Here is what the mapping API say:
[image]

**note** that if I call `GET index/_mapping` I see the field is actually a `text` field ... is this a bug in Kibana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I see what is happening here, the dynamic field creation mechanism creates a `text` when it encounters a string property in the incoming JSON document ...

but it also creates a `keyword` field under the mapping `FIELD.keyword` so we technically get the best of both worlds ... kind of confusing but interesting feature nonetheless

[Link to Doc Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/dynamic-field-mapping.html)